# Deserialize JSON into an array of class instances using Symfony Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON into a DTO class, which has a property types as `NestedDto[]`. Unfortunately, the objects inside the array are deserialized as arrays, not instances of `NestedDto`.
My DTO classes are like:

```php
class TestDto
{
    /**
    * @var NestedDto
    */
    public NestedDto $c;

    /**
     * @var NestedDto[] $cs
     */
    public array $cs;
}

class NestedDto
{
    public string $s;
}
```

The code that orchestrates this use-case (I will show the code for the serializer at the end of the question):

```php
function main() {
    $serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    $json = '{"c":{"s":"nested"},"cs":[{"s":"nested1"},{"s":"nested2"}]}';
    $dto = $serializer->fromJSON(TestDto::class, $json);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($dto, true) . '</pre>';
    $response = $serializer->toJSON($dto);
    exit($response);
}
```

You can see that the property `c` is a proper `NestedDto`, but inside the `cs` array we have two arrays instead of two `NestedDto` instances.

```
TestDto Object
(
    [c] => NestedDto Object
        (
            [s] => nested
        )

    [cs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [s] => nested1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [s] => nested2
                )
        )
)
```

Here is the code for the `JsonSerializer` class which is a wrapper around the Symfony serializer:

```php
final class JsonSerializer
{

    private Serializer $serializer;
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    /**
     * JsonSerializer constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];

        $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
        $normalizers = [
            new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, NULL, NULL, new ReflectionExtractor()),
            new ArrayDenormalizer(),
            new DateTimeNormalizer(),
        ];

        $this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $this->validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();
    }

    /**
     * Create a DTO class from json. Will also auto-validate the DTO.
     * @param $classFQN string The class FQN, e.g. \App\Something\CreateQuoteDTO::class
     * @param $json string The string containing JSON we will use for the DTO.
     * @return array|mixed|object An instance of the $class.
     */
    public function fromJSON( string $classFQN, string $json )
    {
        $instance = $this->serializer->deserialize($json, $classFQN, 'json');
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($instance);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid DTO.');
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Convert a class instance to JSON string
     * @param $object
     * @return string
     */
    public function toJSON( $object ) : string
    {
        return $this->serializer->serialize($object, 'json');
    }

}
```

I have read all of the similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I fail to find what is missing in my code. My guess is something isn't wired up correctly in the normalizers used in JsonSerializer, but after spending an inordinate amount of time on this, I'm out of clues.

Here's all the code in a sandbox where you can run it: [phpsandbox.io](https://phpsandbox.io/n/jolly-haze-bbdg)

Just in case, the packages I've required with composer for this example are:

```
"symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
"symfony/validator": "*",
"doctrine/annotations": "*",
"doctrine/cache": "*",
```

Comment: Can you trying using an `ObjectNormalizer` bound to a [`PhpDocExtractor`](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/components/property_info.html#phpdocextractor)?

Comment: Can you cross-verify your problem with the shared sandbox link, as I have forked your link, and upon serializing I am getting an array of NestedDto in $cs variable.
Working Solution: https://phpsandbox.io/n/fragrant-field-wgn5

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks, I have managed to fix my issue thanks to you. Once I figured out that I need to look for PhpDocExtractor, finding the solution in the web has become quite trivial. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your link, and upon serializing I am getting an array of NestedDto in $cs variable. Working Solution: https://phpsandbox.io/n/fragrant-field-wgn5